# What features does the Outlook "Deleted Items" folder have that user-created folders do not?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I'm using Outlook 2010 and Exchange 2007.

Does the Outlook 2010 (or any version) "Deleted Items" folder have any special traits beyond:

- The "Empty Folder" option when you right-click it
- Settings that control purge timing and so on

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're on an Exchange server, the administrators have some additional control over the retention period of items in the "Deleted Items" folder. That's all the additional functionality I know of, though.

Answer (score 1):

It also has a function for automatic deletion of the folder contents when exiting Outlook. The setting is configurable in the Options as described here: [How to prevent automatic emptying of Deleted Items when exiting Outlook 2010?](https://superuser.com/q/406386/91656)