# How to prevent automatic emptying of Deleted Items when exiting Outlook 2010?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, automation

I've just started using a new PC running Outlook 2010 and I'm trying to set my preferred options. In Outlook 2007 on my previous PC, I had changed the settings so that the Deleted Items folder was not automatically emptied when I exit the application.

However, I can't find that option in Outlook 2010. Can someone please tell me where it is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click on the "File" tab, and select "Options".

Switch to the "Advanced" pane, and clear the "Empty Deleted Items folders when exiting Outlook" option:

[image: Advanced Options pane]

Comment: Thanks! I went through the "Mail" options carefully, but I guess it's not just mail that ends up in the Deleted Items folder, so the Advanced options might make more sense.

Comment: This option is checked but disabled for me (i.e. I can't uncheck the box). Any idea why this might be?

Comment: @ThomCarver [I believe](http://www.symantec.com/connect/forums/preventing-emtpy-deleted-items-folder-working-outlook) there's a [Group Policy that can disable this option](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=18968) - typically Sys Admins would clear this and then disable access to ensure items are retained correctly.